# If $M_x \neq N_y$ then is the differential not exact?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to determine the validity of the following statement:

**Suppose you have a given differential $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy$. If $M_x\neq N_y$ then the differential is not exact.**

My answer is that the statement is false since $M(x,y)$ and $N(x,y)$ have to be continuous with continuous first partials, then the differential is exact if $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$

$M_x$ and $N_y$ are kind of irrelevant as far as I can see for determining whether the differential is exact. Am I correct? Also, I was wondering if the continuity part of the theorem plays a role at all in this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the statement is false. Consider the following $1$-form on $\mathbb R^2$:
$$\omega=x^2dx+y^2dy\in\Omega^1(\mathbb R^2)$$
The exactness of $\omega$ is easy to check. For example: $$\omega=dU,\:\:U=\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{y^3}{3}+c$$
Alternatively, $\omega$ is exact since it is a closed $1$-form on a simply connected differentiable manifold.
But we have that: $$2x=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}x^2\neq\frac{\partial}{\partial y}y^2=2y$$